# How to "show all" in a listing using SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have a dropdownlist that is pulling the categories from a database.  When a user selects a category, the repeater shows only those records, which is correct functionality. My question is how do I make the first option (-- Filter by category --), which is not a category in the database, simply return all the records.  Here is the code behind for the page:

```
protected void PopulateCategories()
{
    category myCategory = new category();
    category[] myCategoryList = myCategory.Listing("title ASC");

    ddlCategories.Items.Add("-- Filter by category --");

    foreach (category category in myCategoryList)
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(category.title, category.category_id);
        ddlCategories.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

protected void ListVideos(string inCategoryID)
{
    videoList = new List<video>();
    video v = new video();

    videoList.AddRange(v.ListingByCategory(inCategoryID));
    repeater.DataSource = videoList;
    repeater.DataBind();
}

protected void ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListVideos(ddlCategories.SelectedValue);        
}
```

And here is the class file for the listing:

```
#region ListingByCategory()
// ****************************
public video[] ListingByCategory(string inCategoryID)
{
    SqlConnection dbconn = BaseClass.ReturnDbConn();

    List<video> listArray = new List<video>();

    try
    {
        dbconn.Open();

        this.SB.Remove(0, this.SB.Length);
        this.SB.Append("SELECT DISTINCT v.*, c.display_name ");
        this.SB.Append("FROM video v ");
        this.SB.Append("INNER JOIN contributor c ON c.contributor_id = v.contributor_id ");
        this.SB.Append("INNER JOIN video_category vc ON vc.video_id = v.video_id ");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inCategoryID))
        {
            this.SB.Append("WHERE vc.category_id = " + SQLUtility.SQLPrep(inCategoryID) + " ");
        }

        this.SB.Append("ORDER BY v.video_id ASC");
        this.SQL = this.SB.ToString();
```

This is only a section of it, I know not all the curly braces are there, but I did not want to overload with the entire file.

Please let me know if I need to provide additional code. This is in C#. I don't think this is a hard solution, just one that is eluding me right now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of string concatenation to supply values (even if you do sanitize them yourself), you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with legacy code.  This project is enormous and done all in a "hack and slash" type format.

Comment: What's not working with your `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inCategoryID))` test? I'd think that would do nicely.

Comment: I thought so too, but I think the '(inCategoryID)' it is getting is the string "--Filter by category --" and since there are no records attached with that "category", it shows nothing.

Comment: You can simply add it with a value: `new ListItem("--Filter by category --", string.Empty)`.